# Как правильно составить SQL запрос с leftJoin

Tags: sql, laravel

Есть такой SQL запрос:

```
   $massMedias = DB::table('posts')
      ->select('posts.*', 'categories.name as category')
      ->leftJoin('categories', 'posts.categories', '=', 'categories.id')
      ->get();
```

В таблице `posts` есть поле `categories` в нем значение `1,2,4` это id в таблице `categories` для каждой категории.

Как мне в итоге при выводе эти цифры заменить на значения категорий на такое `Новости,Благосостояние,Политика` ?

Comment: Или в виде массива получить категории, мне главное получить название категории

Comment: Связывать, используя FIND_IN_SET. затем группировать и собрать вместе с помощью GROUP_CONCAT.